# CSS button animation won't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to get an animation to execute on hover for some buttons in my page.  I wrote the following CSS to achieve this:

```
#B1 {
  margin: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #f7f7f7;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  transition: .3s;
  &:after {
    position: absolute;
    transition: .3s;
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 3px;
    background: #f7f7f7;
  }
}
```

The animation is supposed to load up a small bar at the bottom part of the buttons located at the black div at the bottom of the page, however, my animation does not work. What is causing the problem?

https://codepen.io/Feners4/pen/KggAwg

Comment: _"However, my animation does not work."_ Can you describe "does not work"? What is expected result?

Comment: The buttons rotate when I hover over them

Comment: Yes...? They do rotate? What is the problem? Use coherent sentences, explain what you want, what isn't working, and provide proper code-examples.

Comment: B1 from my CSS snippet points out which buttons I am talking about.. I believe this was enough to point that out..

Comment: Please provide a distraction-free code example. There is a lot of code that does not belong to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide width to display the bar when you hover on the element.

use the below css to get the desired result.

```
 #B1 {
  margin: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #f7f7f7;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  transition: .3s;
  &:after {
    position: absolute;
    transition: .3s;
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 3px;
    background: #f7f7f7;
  }
}

#B1:hover::after {
    width:100%
 }

#B2:hover::after {
    width:100%
 }
```

pen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LxYEdX

Comment: Mind answering a brief question I have regarding this in chat?

Comment: @feners sure , ping me

Comment: How can I ping you?

Comment: ohh okk, you can ping me on skype , user id - dare2701

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set the bar style value after mouseover.

When you mouseover the button, the bar width will be changed to 100% in the button.

Please add the CSS style "**&:hover:after {width: 100%;}**" in #B1 and #B2

Codepen : http://codepen.io/onyoon7/pen/rjNaov

```
#B1 {
  margin: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #f7f7f7;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  transition: .3s;
  &:after {
    position: absolute;
    transition: .3s;
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 3px;
    background: #f7f7f7;
  }
  &:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

#B2 {
  margin: 50px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #f7f7f7;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  transition: .3s;
  &:after {
    position: absolute;
    transition: .3s;
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 3px;
    background: #f7f7f7;
  } 
  &:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```